# Xamarin dictionary null pointer exception on iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have this piece of code, located on Xamarin core project:

```
response.LastPlayed = dto?.Scores["lastPlayed"] ?? "";
```

dto.Scores is a Dictionary < string, string >, when dto or Scores is null it throws an exception even there are null safety operators and it **only ocurrs on iOS**.

I suspect it happens because of some internal code in Xamarin, it differs between platforms but, does anyone have a good explanation?

Comment: Can you post the exception? It's possible you're actually get a [KeyNotFoundException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception?view=netframework-4.8) which the null safety operator wouldn't catch.

Comment: It throws a null pointer exception, I thought that too but the thing is, since dto is null and you're checking it with dto? <-- .Scores["lastPlayed"] ?? ""; it shouldn't even try to find "lastPlayed" in the dictionary. I think it has to do with the implementation it has in iOS...

Comment: If dto or Scores is null, you will get a null pointer exception certainly as you are performing actions on a null object which iOS is not allowed.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter if you make a null safe call when checking on a dictionary, it still crashes. It didn't happen in android because it catches it internally.